# ESP8266 module programming, usb port not defined

Tags: arduino, usb, putty, esp8266

I am trying to connect a esp8266 wi-fi module via a usb ttl converter to PC, but the device manager is not showing any well established port for the given connection. The only thing device manager shows out is a "CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller" and hence Putty is not identifying the port.
Kindly help me out.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Your issue seems doesn't related to esp8266. As you can see i the image "drivers not installed". But be careful connecting this wifi module to usart ttl. Because ttl is 5V, but esp8266 is a 3.3V device and you can damage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to install the drivers from here: https://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/USBtoUARTBridgeVCPDrivers.aspx

Then you need to make sure your power supply for the ESP8266 has an output of 3.3v.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But now, another problem is arising. Putty is non responsive to my AT commands. The terminal displays in a loop the message " ready WIFI DISCONNECT". Hoping to get a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-download the latest driver. 
Mine was working perfectly fine for about 4 months and then out of nowhere it stopped working. (I suspect it stopped working because of some windows updates I did on my machine.)

I tried reinstalling with an older .exe install file and it wasn't solved. It wasn't until I actually re-downloaded the file again (from https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers) and then it worked!

Hope this helps!